# Chatter Email notification under one name

Tags: chatter, community, salesforce-id

Is it possible to receive email notifications in chatter under one common name? Currently we have a chatter group with 10 members in it. We want that whoever posts in it, the email notification that comes to everyone in that group should be from one common name. ie. if Mr X, Mr Y, or anyone in that group posts anything other members should receive notification such as "Admin posted something". Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Enable Organization wide email. and specify unique email address then include list of members in u r group,to this address.So that a unqiue email address will be shared among them.